# React app sees environment variables only in .env file and not in app-level variables on DO

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, digital-ocean

[I’m new to React.js] We have a React.js frontend app with Dango back-end both deployed to the DigitalOcean. On both ends we use environment variables. Our back-end can see and use env vars set on DO, but our frontend sees the variables only if they are stored in the `.env` file and not on DO. However, we want to move our environment variables to the App-level variables on DO (just as we do on our backend side with django), but unfortunately, they are not picked up by our React app from there, although they are correctly printed to the DO console by `printenv`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.